# Partitions processing stuck until state store is rebuilt during rebalancing in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, rebalancing

Let's assume I have stateful Kafka Streams application that consumes data from topic with 3 partitions. At the moment I have 2 instances of the above application running. Let's put it like that: `instance1` have partitions `part1` and `part2` assigned, `instance2` has `part3`.

So now I want to add the new instance to utilize the parallelization completely.

In my understanding, as soon as I start a new instance, the rebalancing occurs: one of partitions `part1` or `part2` and corresponding local state stores will be migrated from the existing instance to the newly added instance. In this example, let's imagine that `part1` migrates on `instance3`.

At the same time, I realize that new instance `instance3` will not start processing new data until it restores the local state store from the changelog topic, which may take much time.

During the period from starting the application and until it restores the state store:

- does it mean that the data from `part1` is not being processed and stuck until `instance3` finishes the start up?
- if yes, then what are the approaches to estimate how much time will it take for `instance3` to build the local state store?
- during this time, are other instances not affected by rebalancing and keep processing data with no downtime (`instance1 - part2`, `instance2 - part3`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebalancing has evolved with the recent releases:

from version 2.4.0 with [KIP-429](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-429%3A+Kafka+Consumer+Incremental+Rebalance+Protocol)

- the incremental cooperative rebalancing is added that came instead of the stop-the-world rebalancing protocol
- optimized for cloud in sense of better rebalance behavior for falling out members (e.g. when Pod is dead and restarts)
- consumer does not need to revoke a partition if the group coordinator reassigns the same partition to the consumer again

=> `part2` and `part3` are not stuck and continued to be processed

from version 2.6.0 with [KIP-441](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-441%3A+Smooth+Scaling+Out+for+Kafka+Streams)

- improve Kafka Streams scaling out behavior, especially for stateful tasks
- previously some tasks have been blocked in processing until the state store is rebuilt which may take hours
- now the new instance first tries to catch-up the state store from change log and only then takes the task as active
- no downtime during the scale out

=> `part1` continues to be processed on `instance1` until `instance3` rebuilds the state store for `part1` and ready to hand over of its processing

Answer (score 0):

The rebalance upon adding of the new instance is at consumer group level. What this means is that all the partitions assigned to all the consumers of the consumer group would be revoked and then re-distributed. So all the partitions - part1, part2 and part3 would be stuck till the rebalancing is complete.

Now to estimate the downtime is a bit tricky. You could emit events on rebalance trigger and consumption start - then compute the time difference between the two events to get an estimate of downtime. If you have a simple java consumer logs, you can also get a rough estimate as all relevant logs (partitions revoked as well as partitions assigned) are already present.